# prompting the user for a file to save data in

Tags: c++

what i want to do is to prompt the user for a file to save the data in what i have tried is :

```
  string save;
  cout<<"Enter filename to save (ex: file.txt): ";
  cin>>save;
  ofstream myfile;
  myfile.open(save);
  myfile <<"ID \tName \tSales\n";
```

however i get an error: no matching function for call to ‘std::basic_ofstream >::open(std::string&)’

EDIT:

So i have updated my code but this doesn't allow me to enter the name of the file. why is that

```
  char file_name[81];
  cout<<"Enter filename to save (ex: file.txt): ";
fflush(stdin);
  cin.getline(file_name, 81);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
cin >> filename;
```

which stops after the first token, you should probably use

```
getline(cin, filename);
```

so you can input filenames with spaces.

Also, consider to use argv (and maybe some library for option parsing).

Answer (score 3):

There is no constructor or `open` function taking an `std::string` in C++03: `myfile.open(save.c_str());`. However, they added them in C++11.

Here is a [nice reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open). Notice the `since C++11` note next to the `std::string` version.

Answer (score 1):

The constructor is explicit and expects a variable of type **const char ***, therefore you'll have to pass save.c_str(), which returns a const char * for the string object.

Comment: can you help me to figure out why now i can't write the name of the file that i want to write in

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program demonstrating what you want to do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string filename;
    cout << "Enter filename to save (eg. file.txt): ";
    cin >> filename;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open(filename.c_str());
    myfile << "ID \tName\tSales" << endl;
    myfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```